# For the cost function question (equation in image), I have found TVC as AVC*P. However the MC curve derived is giving imaginary number solution

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, marginal, cost-functions, numerical-methods

[image]For the cost function question (equation in image), I have found TVC as AVC*P.    However MC curve is showing an imaginary number as solution.

Comment: Can you please show us your attempt at solution? By our rules on self-study questions askers have to show effort by showing their attempt at solving the problem. Also please use mathjax for equations not pictures

Comment: Costs are averaged over quantity, not price, so your TVC is wrong.